# Swift Closure to String

Tags: string, swift, closures

Is it possible to parse a closure as string at runtime in Swift? For example:

```
let y = 5
let myClosure = { (x: Double) -> Double in
    return x * 2 + y
}
```

should give me `"x * 2 + 5"` (for example a function call `closureToString(myClosure)`). Is it possible to do something like this? Btw, I really mean at runtime because `y` could be read from Command Line for example.

I don't think it's possible, just looking for confirmation^^ thank you ;)

Comment: Yeah, would be great if you told me _how_ it is possible :P

Comment: I never used it, but watched a few high level tutorials about closures in youtube. I do not exactly remember where I saw this, but you can find out with a little search

Comment: you should not forget the simple basic concept that closure  is nothing but a function with no name .Anonymous function. Use this to modify your neeeds . Im not gunna give you the code I want you to learn . Try it. Its interesting

Comment: @sriramhegde The problem is I don't know how I could do that -- neither with closures nor with functions. Maybe you could give me a link or something? I prefer learning anyway but I can't learn anything without having any material

Comment: I can but its not clear as to what you want xactly , do you want to parse the returned value or you want it as in the format "x * 2 = y"

Comment: @sriramhegde just the parsed value as mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Im assuming y is a parameter along with x if not remove it .
// Im returning tuples to access both stringValue and DoubleValue
    let myClosure = { (x: Double, y:Double) -> (DoubleValue: Double, StringValue:String) in
        return (x * 2 + y,"\(x) * 2 + \(y)")
    }


let MyClosureResult = myClosure(2,8)
// to accessString Value
MyClosureResult.StringValue
// to access DoubleValue 
MyClosureResult.DoubleValue
```

Comment: accept the answer if this what you were looking for Thank You.

Comment: Yes, I thought there was some other way but this is pretty nice, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need it in a function? Couldn't you do something like this?

```
let y = 5
let myClosure = { (x: Double) -> Double in
    println("x * 2 + \(y), x = \(x)")
    return x * 2 + y
}
```

Comment: I wanted to solve an equation by constructing a tree and do some calculations with it. However, it would be pretty nice if this would work with compile time type checking instead of passing strings and maybe even a dictionary for the variables being used (like you do when constructing layout constraints in code)

Comment: do you want to parse the result of that closure I mean returned value ? if you parse the returned value you will be parsing it something like "\\(10)"